# Is the hadoop cluster configuration possible? what are minimum disk space requirements?

Tags: java, memory, hadoop, bigdata

My hadoop clusters are based on Virtual Machine. Following is the configuration:

**1 master and 9 slaves.**

**master:**

disk space: 20GB

memory: 16G

CPU cores: 8

**slave1 ~ slave9:**

disk space: 5GB

memory: 16G

CPU cores: 8

I know the disk space is too slow, but my data is not very large(about 10GB), so I think it's enough. also my mapper(no reducer) is very simple. The output is not larger than 5GB.

When I test it using 2GB datas(have uploaded HDFS). It is always the following error:

> Container
>   [pid=17619,containerID=container_1400594068017_0014_01_000009] is
>   running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.0 GB of 1 GB
>   physical memory used; **11.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used**. Killing
>   container.

Yes, I need to increase the JVM. But, what I'm wondering is: **how the virtual memory computes, why does it need 11.8GB(larger than slaves disk space)?
Is it the reason that my slaves' disk space too low? or is there other reason? Configuration problem? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: "Is it the reason that my slaves' disk space too low? " - I hope it so..